# Vectorizing trigrams with all possible 3-grams - Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, n-gram

I'm trying to create a 3-gram model to apply machine learning techniques.

Basically I'm trying as follow:

```
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import itertools

my_array = ['worda', 'wordb']
vector = CountVectorizer(analyzer=nltk.trigrams,ngram_range=(3,3))
vector.fit_transform(my_array)
```

My vocabulary:

```
{('o', 'r', 'd'): 0,
('r', 'd', 'a'): 1,
('r', 'd', 'b'): 2,
('w', 'o', 'r'): 3}
```

None of my words have spaces or special characters.
So when I run this:

```
tr_test = vector.transform(['word1'])
print(tr_test)
print(tr_test.shape)
```

I get this return:

```
(0, 0)  1
(0, 1)  1
(0, 3)  1
(1, 4) #this is the shape
```

I think this is right... at least makes sense...
But I would like to represent each word with a matrix containing all 3-gram possibilities. So, each work would be represented by a (1x17576) matrix.
Now I'm using 1x4 matrix (in this particular case), because my vocabulary is built based on my data.

17576 (26ˆ3)- Represents all 3 letters combination in the alphabet (aaa, aab, aac, etc...)

I tried to set my vocabulary to an array with all 3-grams possibilities, like this:

```
#This creates an array with all 3 letters combination
#['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', ...]
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 3)]
vector = CountVectorizer(analyzer=nltk.trigrams,ngram_range=(3,3), vocabulary=keywords)
```

This didn't work... Someone can figure out how to do this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to change the analyzer to 'char', and it seems to work now:

```
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 3)]
vector = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(3,3), vocabulary=keywords)
tr_test = vector.transform(['word1'])
print(tr_test)
```

And the output is:

```
  (0, 9909)  1
  (0, 15253) 1
```

Just as a check:

```
test = vector.transform(['aaa aab'])
print(test)
```

The output:

```
(0, 0)  1
(0, 1)  1
```